# Place Variable into a Specific Location [row,column] Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, index-error

I've been working to place a string variable "revenue" into a pandas dataframe `df1`. As you can see, I used df.ait.

More details about the code: It's about finding the specific date row, by m counting loop.

My issue occurs at the `.iat`.

```
if info[1] == "1": #Get Kikko1
    listofdates = df.Date.tolist() 
    m = 0
    for i in listofdates:
        if i != date: #Counting the rows
            m = m+1
        elif i == date: #Select the row with the matched date
            df.iat[m, 9] = "revenue"
            break
```

The error says:

```
IndexError: index 36 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 31
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the main benefits of using a package like pandas is to avoid this kind of manual looping, which is very difficult to follow and modify.

I think you can do what you need to in one line. Something like:

```
df1.loc[date, 9] = 'revenue'
```

If that doesn't work, could you edit into your question some example data and your desired output?